# Nodejs Connect/Express how session manage memory

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I have been reading up a little on the source for Connect and Express of how session is managed. I am still learning the basics on sessions but I do not understand how the memory is handled.

I know that the server holds the session data in memory and uses a session id to access the data. The server sends the cookie (I am guessing session cookie?) that holds the id and when the user accesses the site, the session is used again.

This is a silly question but my question is how does the memory get managed say if the user deletes his cookies or expires without renewing the session timeout? Does the data stay in memory forever?

I looked at PHP and other languages and saw documentation of how they clean up sessions. It seems they have a garbage collector (scans and deletes expired sessions). Does Connect/Express have this functionality?

Comment: I expect it not to do so. I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Connect `MemoryStore` (the default session storage module for the `Session` middleware) will *not* garbage-collect expired sessions. It only checks their expiration when they are *accessed* (at which point it *will* delete the storage if the session is expired), so if the user clears their cookies, the session will never be accessed again, and will never expire from the `MemoryStore`. Hence [the warning at the `Session` middleware docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html#warning) that `MemoryStore` shouldn't be used in production.

Connect does not provide other session storage modules and expects you to supply your own, building on the abstract `Store` module included with the `Session` middleware.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess a way to do it is to run a setTimeout timer to scan the session object and clean it?

Comment: It would be better to implement your own module descended from `Store` and implement the storage in a way that allows you to easily find stale sessions.